# How can I fix the website's splash page to work in IE8 and below?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, splash-screen, mousehover

I have been trying to figure out for the longest time how I can get the splash page on this website to work correctly in IE8 and below?  Right now, it works on all the other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari).  Here is the website:

http://gds.parkland.edu/student/fall10/gds220/ashipley/p2/final_revised/index.html

jQuery code:

```
/* Sliding Affect Splash Page */
$(function() {
    $('.box').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $.data(this, 'css', { 
            width: $this.css('width'),
            background: $this.css('background-image') 
        });
    });
});

function restore() {
    $('.box').each(function() {
        var orig = $.data(this, 'css');
        $(this).animate({
            width: orig.width
        },{queue:false});
        $(this).css({backgroundImage: orig.background});
    });
}

/* box 1 */
function boxHover(){
        $('.box').stop().animate({'width' : '596px'},{queue:false});
}

function box1master(){
        $('.box2').css({backgroundImage: 'url(images/splash/zatgun_midtop.jpg)'});
        $('.box3').css({backgroundImage: 'url(images/splash/zatgun_midbottom.jpg)'});
        $('.box4').css({backgroundImage: 'url(images/splash/zatgun_bottom.jpg)'});
}
function box2master(){
        $('.box1').css({backgroundImage: 'url(images/splash/bryan_top.jpg)'});
        $('.box3').css({backgroundImage: 'url(images/splash/bryan_midbottom.jpg)'});
        $('.box4').css({backgroundImage: 'url(images/splash/bryan_bottom.jpg)'});
}
function box3master(){
        $('.box1').css({backgroundImage:'url(images/splash/galleries_top.jpg)'});
        $('.box2').css({backgroundImage: 'url(images/splash/galleries_midtop.jpg)'});
        $('.box4').css({backgroundImage: 'url(images/splash/galleries_bottom.jpg)'});
}
function box4master(){
        $('.box1').css({backgroundImage: 'url(images/splash/contact_top.jpg)'});
        $('.box2').css({backgroundImage: 'url(images/splash/contact_midtop.jpg)'});
        $('.box3').css({backgroundImage: 'url(images/splash/contact_midbottom.jpg)'});
}


$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.box1').hover(function(){
        boxHover();
        box1master();
    }, function(){      
        restore();
    });

    $('.box2').hover(function(){
        boxHover();
        box2master();       
    }, function(){      
        restore();
    });

    $('.box3').hover(function(){
        boxHover();
        box3master();
    }, function(){      
        restore();
    });

    $('.box4').hover(function(){
        boxHover();
        box4master();
    }, function(){      
        restore();
    });

});
```

I wonder if I could change the spacing in-between each of the boxes using jQuery or if I somehow have to do this in the CSS/HTML?

Another item I've been messing with within the HTML of the website is:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>

<style text="text/css">
.box2, .box3, .box4 { margin-top: 132px; }
</style>

<![endif]-->
```

Whenever I change the margin to padding, it doesn't work the same.  Whenever I hover over it as of now, it's spaced out correctly but pushes the content on the right to the edge, not showing the boxes on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

When I load up it in IE8 I get this error

> Object doesn't support this property
>   or method  slide_splash.js, line 81
>   character 1

This is line 81

```
$.preloadImages(['zatgun_midtop.jpg', 'zatgun_midbottom.jpg', 'zatgun_bottom.jpg', 'bryan_top.jpg', 'bryan_midbottom.jpg', 'bryan_bottom.jpg', 'galleries_mtop.jpg', 'galleries_midtop.jpg', 'galleries_bottom.jpg', 'contact_top.jpg', 'contact_midtop.jpg', 'contact_midbottom.jpg']);
```

What is this preloadImages and where does it come from. You never pasted it as part of your code.

Is it from this?

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/preloadImages

If so I think you need to download the plugin to use it. I am also getting it in firefox the same error.

```
$.preloadImages is not a function
[Break On This Error] $.preloadImages(['zatgun_midtop.jpg', ...idtop.jpg', 'contact_midbottom.jpg']);
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me this.  I forgot to initially download the preload jQuery plugin.  But initially in Internet Explorer, two of the squares on both sides are right across from each other, not giving the initial affect you see in Firefox (which is the squares have a padding of 66px).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you chobo2 for your answer!  That definitely helped me a lot.

But I found out the reason why the divs were pushing each other around was because of the position and margins being read into IE.

What I had to do was the following:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>

<style text="text/css">
.box2, .box4{ top: 132px; }
.box3, .box4{ top: 264px; }
.box1, .box3{ position: absolute; }
.box2, .box4{ position: relative; }
a:hover { cursor: pointer; }
</style>

<![endif]-->
```

You can see the results in any browser now [here](http://abrielshipley.com/websites/zatgun/index.html).